# Classification of Specht Modules

Tags: representation-theory

How do you "classify" Specht Modules? As you surely know, Specht Modules are irreducible representations of the symmetric group of n letters. I have been working on finding Specht Modules of Symmetric G. for n=3,4,5, and constructing their character tables. Now we arrived to the study of the Hook L. Formula for finding their dimensions.We know that representations of dimension 1 are irreducible, but what about of representaions of dimension two? For example, is there some sort of classification of Specht modules of dimension 2 or 3, and so on? Where can I read about it?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a classification of Specht modules. The Specht mdules classify the irreducible modules, and are in turn described quite explicitly.

Comment: I do not know how to explain you the idea, for example, if I want to classify , for all n, all Specht modules of a given dimension, take dim=2?

Comment: What would a classification look like? You mean classify those partitions for which the Specht module has dimension $2$?

Comment: Oh, yes, I think so...